# If my target variable is binary, is it better to use Pearson's or Spearman's for my correlation vector?

Tags: feature-selection, correlation, pearsons-correlation-coefficient, spearmans-rank-correlation

I'm using a corr vector, combined with RFE, to perform feature selection.

I keep reading conflicting things online as to whether I should use Pearson's or Spearman's...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pearson's correlation coefficient** measures the linear relationship between two continuous variables and assumes that the data is normally distributed. **Spearman's correlation coefficient** measures the monotonic relationship between two variables, which means that it does not assume a linear relationship, but still assumes that the data is at least ordinal. However, when the target variable is binary, it is not appropriate to use either of these correlation coefficients.

It is generally better to use the **point-biserial correlation coefficient.**

**Point-biserial correlation coefficient(PBC)** is a **measure of the association between a binary variable and a continuous variable**, and it is specifically designed for the case when the target variable is binary. It ranges from $-1$ to $1$, where $-1$ indicates a perfect negative association between the variables, $0$ indicates no association, and $1$ indicates a perfect positive association.

The **Point-biserial correlation coefficient** can be calculated using the following formula:

$r_{pb} = (M_1 - M_0) / (SD * sqrt(p * (1-p)))$

where:

- $r_{pb}$ is the point-biserial correlation coefficient
- $M_1$ is the mean of the continuous variable for the group with binary value $1$
- $M_0$ is the mean of the continuous variable for the group with binary value $0$
- $SD$ is the standard deviation of the continuous variable
- $p$ is the proportion of observations with binary value $1$

The **PBC** can be calculated in Python using the `pointbiserialr` function from the `scipy.stats` module:

```py
from scipy.stats import pointbiserialr
r_pb, p_value = pointbiserialr(binary_variable, continuous_variable)
```

where,

`binary_variable` and `continuous_variable` are *numpy arrays* or *pandas series* containing the *binary variable* and *continuous variable*, respectively. The function returns the **PBC** and the associated **p-value.**

Comment: Thank you for this. For using this this for 100+ features, i can only think of building a loop. Do you happen to have any more efficient suggestions? Many thanks.

Comment: Refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72134005/14045537